# Flink 1.10 not connecting to minio (s3)

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, minio

I'm running locally a docker compose running flink and minio
When I try to connect to minio, I always get the following error:

caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.

It seems that the plugin isn't loaded correctly.

my flink config (flink-conf.yaml):

```
state.backend: filesystem
s3.endpoint: http://minio:9000
s3.path.style.access: true
s3.access-key: minio
s3.secret-key: minio123

presto.s3.access-key: minio 
presto.s3.secret-key: minio123  
presto.s3.endpoint: http://minio:9000   
presto.s3.path-style-access: true
```

I've copied the required plugin as following:

```
mkdir -p plugins/s3-fs-presto
cp opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-*.jar plugins/s3-fs-presto
```

Any suggestions?

Stack trace:

The program finished with the following exception:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed. (JobID: 7ae6657256719d8c32d76ba113fb35f0)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:338)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:413)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1652)
    at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:604)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:466)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1008)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1081)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1081)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:259)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error opening the Input Split s3://test/test.txt [0,3243]: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.open(FileInputFormat.java:824)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.open(DelimitedInputFormat.java:470)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.DelimitedInputFormat.open(DelimitedInputFormat.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:450)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:362)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat$InputSplitOpenThread.run(FileInputFormat.java:995)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Hadoop is not in the classpath/dependencies.
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedSchemeFactory.create(UnsupportedSchemeFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:446)
    ... 2 more
#
```

Comment: Solved, task-manager needed the actual plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by the "actual plugins" what else did you do besides copying the jars to plugins dir?